# Hex view of a file

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, hex

I am using Delphi 2009.

I want to view the contents of a file (in hexadecimal) inside a memo.

I'm using this code :

```
var
  Buffer:String;
begin
  Buffer := '';
  AssignFile(sF,Source); //Assign file
  Reset(sF); 
  repeat
    Readln(sF,Buffer); //Load every line to a string.
    TempChar:=StrToHex(Buffer); //Convert to Hex using the function
    ...
  until EOF(sF);
end;

function StrToHex(AStr: string): string;
var
I ,Len: Integer;
s: chr (0)..255;
//s:byte;
//s: char;
begin
  len:=length(AStr);
  Result:='';
  for i:=1 to len  do
  begin
    s:=AStr[i];

    //The problem is here. Ord(s) is giving false values (251 instead of 255)
    //And in general the output differs from a professional hex editor.

    Result:=Result +' '+IntToHex(Ord(s),2)+'('+IntToStr(Ord(s))+')';
  end;
  Delete(Result,1,1);
end;
```

When I declare variable "**s**" as **char** (i know that char goes up to 255) I get results   hex values up to 65535!

When i declare variable "**s**" as **byte** or **chr (0)..255**, it outputs different hex values, comparing to any Hexadecimal Editor!

Why is that? How can I see the correct values?

Check images for the differences.

**1st image**: Professional Hex Editor.

[image: Professional Hex Editor]

**2nd image**: Function output to Memo.

[image: Marked value should be 255 (box character)]

Thank you.

Comment: Surely you should be using `AnsiChar` and `AnsiString` rather than `WideChar` and `UnicodeString`.

Comment: Thanks. Using this code: function String2Hex(const Buffer: Ansistring): string;
begin
  SetLength(result, 2*Length(Buffer));
  BinToHex(@Buffer[1], PWideChar(@result[1]), Length(Buffer));
end;

It worked.

Comment: NO. Your input data in (emphasis→) **array of bytes** (←emphasis). Assumption what you can use **character type** for that led you directly into this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Delphi 2009, a `Char` is the same thing as a `WideChar`, that is, a *Unicode character*. A wide character occupies two bytes. You want to use `AnsiChar`. Prior to Delphi 2009 (that is, prior to Unicode Delphi), `Char` was the same thing as `AnsiChar`.

Also, you shouldn't use `ReadLn`. You are treating the file as a text file with text-file line endings! This is a general file! It might not have any text-file line endings at all!

Comment: @Andreas - how is about `Readln` ? Could you use it for binary files reading ? I'm asking because I was always using `file of byte` for that.

Comment: @daemon_x: No, you cannot use `ReadLn` unless it is a text file with line endings!

Comment: Just use TFileStream or TMemoryStream

Comment: Or better to say; use what Cosmin posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304896/hex-view-of-a-file/6305342#6305342). Note that he is reading `bytes` instead of `chars` so then you don't need to convert char into its ordinary value and then convert it into hex format.

Comment: @daemon_x: forget about "file of", "Read(Ln)", "Write(Ln)". They are obsolete constructs that are superseeded by a more modern approach (streams), and may have issue with large files and so on.

Comment: @ldsandon - I know; that's the reason why I said `I was using` not `I'm using`, but thanks for the hint anyway. OP started with reading a `File` type. In my deleted answer (where was comment about inefficiency) I just wanted to point out to read `Byte` instead of `Char`. I'll rather delete the comments about `File` type to prevent deceptions.

Comment: @daemon_x: sorry, you were the editor, not the OP, I was addressing the OP.

Answer (score 10):

Your Delphi 2009 is unicode-enabled, so `Char` is actually `WideChar` and that's a 2 byte, 16 bit unsigned value, that can have values from 0 to 65535.

You could change all your `Char` declarations to `AnsiChar` and all your `String` declarations to `AnsiString`, but that's not the way to do it. You should drop Pascal I/O in favor of modern stream-based I/O, use a `TFileStream`, and don't treat binary data as `Char`.

Console demo:

```
program Project26;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses SysUtils, Classes;

var F: TFileStream;
    Buff: array[0..15] of Byte;
    CountRead: Integer;
    HexText: array[0..31] of Char;

begin
  F := TFileStream.Create('C:\Temp\test', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    CountRead := F.Read(Buff, SizeOf(Buff));
    while CountRead <> 0 do
    begin
      BinToHex(Buff, HexText, CountRead);
      WriteLn(HexText); // You could add this to the Memo

      CountRead := F.Read(Buff, SizeOf(Buff));
    end;
  finally F.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: I think you want an `fmShareDenyWrite` in there too.

Comment: i don like hiding logic under BinToHex (it will add extra complexity when splitting to octets)

Answer (score 7):

For an easier to read output, and looking better too, you might want to use this simple hex dump formatter.

The HexDump procedure dumps an area of memory into a TStrings in lines of two chunks of 8 bytes in hex, and 16 ascii chars

example

```
406563686F206F66 660D0A6966206578 @echo off..if ex
69737420257E7331 5C6E756C20280D0A ist %~s1\nul (..
0D0A290D0A                        ..)..
```

Here is the code for the dump format function

```
function HexB (b: Byte): String;
 const HexChar: Array[0..15] of Char = '0123456789ABCDEF';
 begin
  result:= HexChar[b shr 4]+HexChar[b and $0f];
 end;

procedure HexDump(var data; size: Integer; s: TStrings);
 const
  sepHex=' ';
  sepAsc=' ';
  nonAsc='.';
 var
  i : Integer;
  hexDat, ascDat : String;
  buff : Array[0..1] of Byte Absolute data;

 begin
  hexDat:='';
  ascDat:='';
  for i:=0 to size-1 do 
   begin
    hexDat:=hexDat+HexB(buff[i]);
    if ((buff[i]>31) and (buff[i]<>255)) then
      ascDat:=ascDat+Char(buff[i])
    else
      ascDat:=ascDat+nonAsc;
    if (((i+1) mod 16)<>0) and (((i+1) mod 8)=0) then 
      hexDat:=hexDat+sepHex;
    if ((i+1) mod 16)=0 then 
     begin
      s.Add(hexdat+sepAsc+ascdat);
      hexdat:='';
      ascdat:='';
     end;
   end;
  if (size mod 16)<>0 then
   begin
    if (size mod 16)<8 then 
      hexDat:=hexDat+StringOfChar(' ',(8-(size mod 8))*2)
              +sepHex+StringOfChar(' ',16)
    else
      hexDat:=hexDat+StringOfChar(' ',(16-(size mod 16))*2);
    s.Add(hexDat + sepAsc  + ascDat);
   end;
 end;
```

And here is a complete code example for dumping the contents of a file into a Memo field.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
  FStream: TFileStream;
  buff: array[0..$fff] of Byte;
  nRead: Integer;
 begin
  FStream := TFileStream.Create(edit1.text, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    repeat
      nRead := FStream.Read(Buff, SizeOf(Buff));
      if nRead<>0 then
        hexdump(buff,nRead,memo1.lines);
    until nRead=0;
  finally
    F.Free;
  end;
 end;
```

Comment: it take forever to load a 2MB file to Tmemo. Is there a way to speed it up?

Answer (score 3):

`string` is `UnicodeString` in Delphi 2009. If you want to use single-byte strings use `AnsiString` or `RawByteString`.

See [String types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/String_Types).